# How to find and delete duplicate bookmarks in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks

How to delete duplicate bookmarks and check their status... is there a Google Chrome extension that do that?

Answer (score 12):

**[SuperSorter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hjebfgojnlefhdgmomncgjglmdckngij)** is a nice Chrome extension that seems to do the job. It's still in beta, but the removal of duplicates seems to work just fine.

[image]

Comment: Reviews claim it's broken.

Answer (score 3):

Bookmark Sentry and Super Sorter both do work, BUT the chrome bookmarks API gives them a quota for changes and as of july 2012, neither extension catches the errors when they exceed their quota for deleting duplicate (or reordering in the case of super sorter) bookmarks.

You can let super sorter run in the background (enable auto mode) and it will do a bunch of retries over time, and that may work around the quota issues with a string of partial successes...   My experience, though, has been that chrome sync keeps disconnecting my browser when i make too many changes.

So the issue is not just deleting the duplicate bookmarks, it's removing them from your synced chrome browser state, which is a bit more complicated because the sync algorithm doesn't like so much change all at once.

Answer (score 1):

There is this chrome extension built for exactly this purpose,

Name : **Bookmarks clean up**

Link : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-clean-up/oncbjlgldmiagjophlhobkogeladjijl

It allows users to find, list and remove duplicated bookmarks manually and in batches, and provides a way to get rid of broken bookmark links (dead links) and empty folders.

You can thank the author at https://www.patreon.com/itwillnotbeasy.

Cheers to productivity! :)

Comment: Reviews claim it's broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found to be working for me.

**[FBS II : Fast Bookmark Scanner II](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fbs-ii-fast-bookmark-scan/gjcmklpilmpfhfjpebhnapnglcppdbic)**

Scan your bookmarks in order to delete duplicated links empty folders or merge duplicated folders. A bêta link checker is include

Just click the link above to get it install in Chrome (add to your chrome). The software allow you to scan for duplicates (within the same folder, or overall) and you are to trigger the respective clean up action to your need.

Its deadlinks (which is in beta) feature doesn't work that well for me though, it reported non-dead links as dead.

Comment: Software recommendations in answers should follow [this outline](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/432690). You can improve your answer by [edit]ing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command line utility:

https://github.com/juvalen/mb-checker

It filters out specified http return codes and optionally removes duplicates